# Inserting row to table, with values two levels deep

Tags: lua, lua-table

When looping through a table trying to add 'sub properties' I get an error that i'm attempting to index field '?'. I am also sure that count and v.name both contain values.

Send help?

```
count = 0
local tbl = {}
for k,v in pairs(list) do
  if string.find(v.name,"Jim") then
    count = count + 1
    tbl[count] = count
    --below throws an error
    --tbl[count]["name"] = {v.name}
  end               
end
```

Comment: `tbl[count] = {["count"] = count}`

Comment: Thank you. How would the syntax look if I included the 'name' property as well?

Comment: `tbl[count] = {count = count, name=v.name}`